# Downgrade crystal reports with visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've developed some crystal reports in Visual Studio 2010. Actually I am updating a client application made in Visual Studio 2008. I have updated the visual studio to 2010 but with .NET3.5. Now for this, a new crystal reports runtime needs to be installed. My client does not want to install this runtime. He wants to use the old runtime as per Visual Studio 2008.

What should be the work around for this problem? or I have to shift back to Visual Studio 2008?

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the CrystalReports Viewer (UI) control and the crystal references it adds to your project. Those are version X and the ones installed with Crystal Runtime 2008 are version Y.

What you need to do is to remove the crystal references added by VS2010 and use the ones installed by the crystal runtime (2008).

check the version of the assemblies to identify which is which.

Answer (score 0):

what is the difference between the old and new runtime?
i use the 2010 visual studio and crystal works fine

Comment: If crystal reports are build in VS-2008 then it works fine with 2010. I want to work other way. Reports build in VS-2010 do not run with the runtime of VS-2008.

Comment: i see, normally you would have to downgrade visual studio, but im not 100% sure